# crypttab: location of luks header file

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

Hi my crypttab looks as follows:

`crypt_device /dev/sda luks,header=/boot/header.img`

`update-initramfs -u -k all` works with success, but for some reason cryptsetup will not find the header.img which resides on the usb stick (that also contains the boot partition) during boot. It is stored on /boot/header.img

(using luks encryption with detached header, and seperate boot partition on usb, os: lubuntu 18)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've taken special steps to mount the `/boot` filesystem under initramfs, it won't be mounted yet. In a default boot sequence, the system only cares about the root filesystem (and possibly the swap partition) while executing in initramfs.

Once the real root filesystem has been checked (if applicable) and mounted, the rest of the filesystems, normally including `/boot`, are mounted. You would need to make some special arrangement to mount the `/boot` filesystem while still in initramfs to gain access to `/boot/header.img`. Or you could just include your `header.img` into initramfs.

Answer (score 0):

Since your USB drive is also your boot drive, the system only loads the initramfs image to memory until the root partition is decrypted and `newroot` is remapped. This is where manual mount of the USB drive would be necessary from within the initramfs or an update to `fstab` needs to be made to mount the partition which contains the key file. Although you mentioned that that during boot it is stored in `/boot/header.img` it's because the USB is no longer mounted when the initramfs is loaded into RAM for the boot processs. Therefore when `crypttab` initiates, `cryptsetup` cant find the /boot/header.img file because the directory for /boot on the USB hasn't been mounted within the initramfs environment which is currently loaded to decrypt your hard drive's root folder.

To be sure, as telcoM explained, if you previously booted into your system and created a keyfile while the OS was unlocked and the partition was decrypted and then placing a copy of the keyfile.img within your `/boot` directory at that point in time (and again, and this is while the system is unencrypted and you're already accessing the system) then it's not the same `/boot` directory you find when you're booting up and the USB contains the boot drive; that's what we're both trying to say. This is because during the boot process, it has opened and copied the *initrd-4.15.33-generic* image (for example) and does not mount automatically the USB device as a storage container.

So to resolve, you need `fstab` to mount the USB to the `/boot` directory so that `crypttab` can locate the directory when it's called for by `cryptsetup`

See the [fstab man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) for explanations if needed for below:
e.g.

```
# First find the UUID of the partition holding your USB thumb drive
$ blkid

# You can also use grep or whatever you're more comfortable with as a text editor
$ nano /etc/fstab

# then add a line for your USB device 
UUID={device partition UUID} {mount point} {filesystem} {mount options}  {dump order}{fsck order}
# Example
UUID=66E53SSD988 /boot ext4  defaults  0 1
```

However, I would suggest mounting the drive somewhere other than in the /boot directory unless that's just the directory within the USB and then modifying crypttab so that there's less confusion between what folder the header.img file is in.

i.e.
`UUID=66E53SSD988 /mnt/usb ext4  defaults  0 1`

Then, in the case of the changed mount point, `crypttab` would in turn need to be changed to the following :

`crypt_device /dev/sda luks,header=/mnt/usb/boot/header.img`

Comment: You could also use a raw partition containing the luks header rather than a partition holding the luks header file. Meaning, apply the header to an unpartitioned space of the USB using dd and designate the UUID as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665861/414107) (and saves the trouble of mounting)